# Django Inline Autocomplete

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

Is it possible to filter an inline autocomplete field by a dynamic value entered by a user?

For example, I have a an admin form where staff enters games information including home and visiting team, game date and time, score, etc. They also enter individual player names and stats. I would like to add a filter to show only the players on either the home or visiting team.

I am using the [InlineAutocompleteAdmin](http://jannisleidel.com/2008/11/autocomplete-form-widget-foreignkey-model-fields/) module, which provides autocomplete hints for input fields.

Here is the current inline autocomplete code:

```
class IndividualFootballGameInline(InlineAutocompleteAdmin):
    model = IndividualFootballGame
    extra = 1
    related_search_fields = {
        'player': ('player__first_name', 'player__last_name', '#team__sport__sport=Football', '#team__season__season_start_date__year=' + str(get_current_season_start_year('football'))),
    }
```

If this can be accomplished, can you explain how?

Comment: Would have been helpful if you'd explained where InlineAutoCompleteAdmin came from in the first place.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: I added a reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InlineAutocompleteAdmin provides a template that I modified to provide this functionality. The file `templates/admin/autocomplete/inline_searchinput.html` defines the jQuery `lookup()` function. I added additional code to check for values in the visiting and home teams field, and to append them to `search_fields` as needed.